# Hi!,Our m3u8 stream not work on Android

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, jwplayer6, http-live-streaming

we tried to solved the android streaming issue..but we still can't figure it out..

only problem is we can't can't get it through android...Other device like-

Desktop,ios device work well..But not work on android
Please!, advice us to solved this issue..

My code as follow:

```
<div id="player" style="width:646px;height:377px;">
</div>
</div>
<script src="http://jwpsrv.com/library/DdkXAvrLEeK6QxIxOUCPzg.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer("player").setup({
        file: "http://rbc.streamguys.com/970wamd/970wamd/playlist.m3u8",

        autostart: true,

        width: "643",
        height: "375",
        primary: "html5",
        androidhls: true
    });
</script>
```

Test link: http://demo.godork.com/

Comment: have you enabled java script on webview?

Comment: Hi!,This in on  plain html page..I tested this using with android 4.4 & android 5 devices... using chrome,opera,Mozila web browsers..None of device display stream...say playable source not found ..Desktop & ipad,iphone works.. any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());
final WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

private class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

}
```

Comment: Hi!... Thanks for your reply- drjunja86.. but it's not work.. i put the above code,inside the javascript tag..but still can't see it's get work. any idea? that help me to solved this issue..